# java code help for temperature sensor(DHT11)

Tags: sensor, java

I've the raspberry pi model b and i am trying to connect a temperature sensor(DHT11). I am facing problem on how to fetch the data from the sensor. I am using JAVA. Which API should i use to get this working? What else should i need to know?

Comment: You will presumably use the same Java API regardless of which processor you use.  That's a big Java selling point.  The question appears to have nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

DHT11 is a n analog o/p temp sensor. so its real easy to use. but on the other side it doesn't have a proper datasheet( it has one but its in Chinese).
so i will suggest use any temp sensor from TI,AD, Honeywell. 
i use [SHT25](https://www.controleverything.com/find?qs=sht25) its low cost and it can do temp and humidity. its accuracy is around 1.8% and 0.2'C.

it comes with I2C communication and real easy to use.
you can find [java,python code here for Pi I2C](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/SHT25).

Answer (score 0):

You need a linux driver that you can call from Java and I don't think that there is one for the DHT11. I have used the code in the book [Raspberry Pi IoT In C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1871962463) which interfaces directly without any drivers. You could do the same but you would either need to call a C function that read the data or write your own GPIO version in Java using [pi4j](http://pi4j.com/) It is difficult to know if Java is fast enough to do the job.